# java class import shows compile error

Tags: java, import, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to make some changes to a legacy code of a plugin which was written using Java version 4. I am trying to extend a class from an imported package.

```
import org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelContext;

public class XMLModelContextForPma extends XMLModelContext
{


}
```

I'm quite new to plugin development. I couldn't figure out why the compiler shows

**The type org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelContext is not visible** error. Also, most of the codes in classes of this particular package are using **.internal.** packages which are giving **Discouraged access** warnings. I'm googled here and there and found it's because of non-standard/API classes.

But this is quite strange. I have the jar files in the build path but not sure what is wrong here.

I'm developing in Eclipse Juno, Mac OS X, Java 6

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the class XMLModelContext is private or protected and in a different package.

If a class is declared as protected, you can only use it in other classes within the same package or any of it's sub packages.

Comment: yeah, i just noticed it has a default identifier so obviously isn't not gonna be visible outside its containing package

Answer (score 0):

Add that jar(org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelContext containing jar) to your project file path.